# Allow user to create instances of custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, links

I have a custom field for a links page which takes a name and an URL and saves it in the post meta. However, I want the user to be able to click "Add new link" and a new custom box appears so they can essentially have unlimited links. Ideally a plugin would be perfect, or any tips into which techniques I should look at.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

you can make repeating fields with the WP alchemy class
http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#have_fields_and_multi